# Using SqlHierarchId throws System.InvalidCastException with Dapper

Tags: .net, dapper, hierarchyid

I want to use SqlHierarchId in my .net project but when I try to read a SqlHierarchId from DB, System.InvalidCastException will occur. I have written a simple code which it's accessible in bellow link, to show this problem:

[SqlHierarchyIdTest](https://github.com/Freydoonk/SqlHierarchyIdTest)

```
var connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=tempdb;Integrated Security=True");
var val = connection.Query<Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlHierarchyId>("select @Path", new {Path = Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlHierarchyId.Parse("/1/2/3/")}).Single();
```

I trace code and reach the `QueryImpl<T>` in `SqlMappe`r class. When Dapper tries to compare the type of value which is read by `SqlDataReader`, to the type of generic, confront two types of `SqlHierarchyId`!

[image: Microsoft.SqlServer.Types]

Comment: What does your connection string look like w.r.t. `TypeSystemVersion` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.typesystemversion(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @ta.speot.is not work

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though one reference is bundled with the Dapper libraries, while the higher version is the one you installed or referenced from your machine.

Try add this to your app.config file to force all assemblies called Microsoft.SqlServer.Types to use the newest version:

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
       <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
       <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Microsoft Docs on assembly redirects: [Microsoft Docs - Redirecting Assembly Versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions)